# How to Manage Private Public Port on Azure (Ubuntu VM)?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, azure, port

I am running my NodeJs application on 4567 port (as it should be greater than 1024) , now I am using (non classic) vm which cannot be accessed from older Azure Portal , so how can I bind(public port 80) with this private port 4567 in new Portal.

[image]

[image]

This is how I created my Linux VM..

[image]

Comment: which template you chose when you created the VM?

Comment: I have used New ->Compute->and then Linux Vm but later I choosed (Resource Manger ) from drop down rather than classic and since then problem begun,I scrapped my whole VM after not able to figure out isssue and now deployed with old classic way and its working fine now..

Comment: Updated that screenshot inquestion as well..

Answer (score 0):

You can manage your endpoints from preview portal. Click VM Item ==>>select your VM name==>>Click your "Setting"==>>Select Endpoint==>>click "ADD" button==>input your public port and private portal.

---

[Update]
Currently VM in Resource Manager Model has a Public IP (PIP) and can be reached directly from the Internet. We can see in your Resource Group an IP. Because of that, there are no more endpoints to create. Instead, you need to operate with the Network Security Group, which is a firewall on the Azure infrastructure as your picture mentioned . Also, you can RDP to your VM and modify the inbound rules. Any concerns, please let me know.

Comment: creating endpoints concept is not available in new type of Vm when you create new Vm select Resource Manager rather than classic then there is new type of Wizard..

Comment: Yes, Resource manager don't provide this item. I will confirm it and come back for you later. Thanks for your patience.